# A truth definition, wrong, but where

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

Consider the theory **ZFC** of language with connectives $\neg$, $\rightarrow$, predicative symbol $\in$ and quantifier $\forall$.

Assume that we are working in **ZFC**.  Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the class of all set.  It is well-known that the notion of satisfaction "$\mathcal{V} \models \varphi$" cannot be defined.  My question is "where does the obstruction lie?".  To be specific, let me proceed in some detail.

An assignment is any function whose domain is the set of all variables.  Suppose that $s$ is an assignment and $x$ is a variable.  Then $s(x|\alpha)$ is an assignment which is the same with $s$ but the value $\alpha$ at $x$.

1. For any assignment $s$, variables $x$ and $y$, define $\mathcal{V} \models_s x \in y$ if $s(x)$ is an element of $s(y)$.
2. $\mathcal{V} \models_s \neg \varphi$ if $\mathcal{V} \not \models_s \varphi$ for every (formal) formula $\varphi$.
3. $\mathcal{V} \models_s (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$ if $\mathcal{V} \not \models_s \varphi$ or $\mathcal{V} \models \psi$.
4. $\mathcal{V} \models_s \forall x \varphi$ if for every $\alpha$, $\mathcal{V} \models_{(s|\alpha)} \varphi$
5. We define $\mathcal{V} \models \varphi$ if $\mathcal{V} \models_s \varphi$ for every assignment $s$.

(where $\mathcal{V} \not \models$ is an abbreviation for "not $\mathcal{V} \models$".)

It seems that "$\mathcal{V} \models $" has been succesfully defined.

Where is the first flaw, if any?

Reading comments, I feel like it will be helpful to make a statement so that it can be tested correct or not.

Let $F$ be the set of all formulas.
By the recursion theorem, for every assignment $s$, there is a function 
$T_s: F \longrightarrow \{0, 1 \}$ 
with the properties

- $T_s (x \in y) = 1$ if and only if $s(x) \in s(y)$.
- $T_s (\neg \varphi)$ if and only if $T_s (\varphi) = 0$.
- $T_s (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$ if and only if $T_s (\varphi) = 0$ or $T_s(\psi) =1$.
- $T_s (\forall x \varphi)$ if and only if for every $\alpha$, $T_{s(x|\alpha)} \varphi =1$.

Comment: How would you verify 4.?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for your comment. It is a part of definition so, at my opinion, I cannot 'verify' it. Ofcourse, step 4 is most suspicious part among the argument. The problem is I cannot see why the argument cannot serve as a definition.

Comment: In order to (even abstractly) determine wheter a formula with $\forall$ id or is not "true", one needs to "know" all possible values $\alpha$, that is the class of all sets, which depends on the model.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm nervous if I go wrong again. With step 4 I did not intend to claim $\mathcal{V} \models_s \forall x \varphi$ in the case $\mathcal{V} \models_{s(x|\alpha)} \varphi$ for each instence of the value of $\alpha$ but introduce the abbreviation $\mathcal{V} \models_s \forall x \varphi$ for  $\forall \alpha \mathcal{V} \models_{s(x|\alpha)} \varphi$.

Comment: I assume your intention is to use the recursion theorem so this informal recursion actually corresponds to a formula? What is the logical complexity of that formula? (that is, can you specify an $n$ so your formula is $\Sigma_n$?)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Hmm.. Actually, I cannot surely grasp the point of your question. Of course my intention is to apply the recursion theorem so that $\mathcal{V} \models \varphi$ is defined for every formula, not formulas with or less complexity than a specific one.

Comment: The statement $\mathcal V\models\varphi$ should actually be a formula $\psi(\dot\varphi)$ where $\dot\varphi$ is the Gödel code for $\varphi$. I am asking about the complexity of $\psi$.

Comment: @seono Andres is pointing out the essential difficulty in the naive definition that you have proposed and (of course) seoneo cannot describe $\psi$ because he hasn't bothered checking if his (metatheoretic) definition can be formalized in ZFC uniformly for all formulas.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Ah, now I see your point.

Comment: @hot_queen Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to inductively defined a class of the form $S = \{(\phi, \vec{x}) : \phi \in \text{Form} \wedge \vec{x} \in V^{\omega} \wedge V \vDash \phi(\vec{x})\}$. The trouble in formalizing this induction within ZFC is in step four. Assigning a truth value to $(\forall v)\phi(v)$ requires checking $\phi(x)$ for all $x \in V$. There is no way to formalize this in ZFC via the usual transfinite induction scheme - Whatever fixed iterative defined function you use can be diagonalized against. Although, one can formalize satisfaction if you are willing to restrict yourself to $\Sigma_n$ formulas. I think Kanamori has some remarks on this in the introductory chapter of his book.

Comment: Historically speaking, I believe that Levy proved the existence of a $\Sigma_{n+1}$ truth predicate for $\Sigma_n$ formulas.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Although I think the result is quite trivial.

Comment: True, it's not a very difficult proof. Let me point out that the proof that $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$ is also a simple proof, borderline trivial. :-)

Comment: I do not agree with your analogy.

Comment: My point is that in retrospect a lot of things can be seen quite trivial. But it takes a keen eye to see that those results are true to begin with (or coming up with the definitions which uncover them).

Comment: OK. I agree with you last statement (but not with your example, maybe for historical reasons).

Comment: @hot_queen By the help of your answer and with many other comments, now I come up with realization what goes wrong with the argument. Yes it cannot be formalized. Your expression S was especially helpful. Yes, Form × M^omega is still a set when M is a set. Ok. I'm finally happy now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here I attach an answer because, although there had been a successful answer, it have takes me some time to recognize what is really a problem to proceed with the argument when we deal with a model which is possibly a proper class.

When we define the notion of satisfaction, with a model with a universe which is a set(anyway, the phrase 'with a universe which is a set' is actually redundant because my the term 'model' we always mean a set. This time, however, for emphasis.) we usually do the same thing.
However, there is still a problem of definiteness with the argument.
We cannot give a 'formula' which defines satisfaction because, we may need higher nested quantifiers to cover more complex formulas.

To resolve this problem, that is, to apply recursion theorem properly, we need to deal with the powerset of the set of all possible assignments as a codomain of the recursion.

- $h(x \in y) = \left\{ s: \textrm{assignment}| s(x) \in s(y) \right\}$ for each pair of variables $x$ and $y$.

...

- $h(\forall x \varphi) = \left\{ s: \textrm{assignment}| \textrm{for ever $\alpha$ in the universe, $s(x|\alpha) \in h(\varphi)$ } \right\}$

Here, you can see the problem occurs when the universe is a proper class.
There is no such a function $h$.